# Create count of categorical column 1 hour ahead and 1 hour behind current time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns: `time_of_day` and  `categorical column`. I want to count the number of values that have the same value in the `categorical_column` that are 1 hour ahead and 1 hour behind the current time:

Example Input:

```
time_of_day         categorical_column
25/05/2023 11:30:00 category1
25/05/2023 11:30:00 category1
25/05/2023 11:45:00 category1
25/05/2023 12:35:00 category1
25/05/2023 13:00:00 category2
25/05/2023 13:30:00 category1
25/05/2023 13:45:00 category1
25/05/2023 14:00:00 category2
25/05/2023 14:15:00 category2
25/05/2023 14:15:00 category1
```

Example Output:

```
time_of_day         categorical_column  window_count
25/05/2023 11:30:00 category1           3
25/05/2023 11:30:00 category1           3
25/05/2023 11:45:00 category1           4
25/05/2023 12:35:00 category1           3
25/05/2023 13:00:00 category2           2
25/05/2023 13:30:00 category1           4
25/05/2023 13:45:00 category1           3
25/05/2023 14:00:00 category2           3
25/05/2023 14:15:00 category2           2
25/05/2023 14:15:00 category1           3
```

e.g. `time_of_day=25/05/2023 11:45:00`  and `categorical_column=category1` has a value of `4` because there are 4 values containing `category1` in range `25/05/2023 10:45:00 - 25/05/2023 12:45:00`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting per group in [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['time_of_day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_of_day'])

def f(s):
    a = s.to_numpy()
    return (abs(a[:,None]-a)<=delta).sum(axis=1)

df['window_count'] = df.groupby('categorical_column')['time_of_day'].transform(f)
```

Output:

```
          time_of_day categorical_column  window_count
0 2023-05-25 11:30:00          category1             3
1 2023-05-25 11:30:00          category1             3
2 2023-05-25 11:45:00          category1             4
3 2023-05-25 12:35:00          category1             3
4 2023-05-25 13:00:00          category2             2
5 2023-05-25 13:30:00          category1             4
6 2023-05-25 13:45:00          category1             3
7 2023-05-25 14:00:00          category2             3
8 2023-05-25 14:15:00          category2             2
9 2023-05-25 14:15:00          category1             3
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nice and easy to understand, however it does have quite high time complexity.

Comment: @DanielWyatt how big are your groups? I'm not sure you can do much better as you need to compare all datetimes to all other ones (at best you could divide the comparisons by 2)

Comment: Yes quite a lot. I have around 5m rows across around a few thousand categories

Comment: You could sort the datetimes and design an algorithm to keep track of the latest "x-1h" and next "x+1h" datetime on a sliding window, but I don't see an easy way to vectorize that

Comment: Yes I can't either. I think I will go with your approach for now and accept the inefficency. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with `rolling()` `with center = True`

```
r = df.assign(window_count = 1).groupby('categorical_column').rolling('2H1S',on ='time_of_day',center=True)['window_count'].sum()

df.join(r.loc[~r.index.duplicated()],on = ['categorical_column','time_of_day'])
```

Output:

```
          time_of_day categorical_column  window_count
0 2023-05-25 11:30:00          category1           3.0
1 2023-05-25 11:30:00          category1           3.0
2 2023-05-25 11:45:00          category1           4.0
3 2023-05-25 12:35:00          category1           3.0
4 2023-05-25 13:00:00          category2           2.0
5 2023-05-25 13:30:00          category1           4.0
6 2023-05-25 13:45:00          category1           3.0
7 2023-05-25 14:00:00          category2           3.0
8 2023-05-25 14:15:00          category2           2.0
9 2023-05-25 14:15:00          category1           3.0
```